# Data type mismatch in MS Access SQL sub-query

Tags: t-sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

Alright, this query will not run and returns a data type mismatch error. This error did not start until I attempted to join two tables within the sub-query in the WHERE clause.

The two tables I am attempting to join are the exact two tables that are joined in the primary query. Each table contains a column, CRD Number. In one table, it is stored as text, in the other, it is stored as number. This is why I have used the CStr() function to cast the numerical column as a textual column. This worked beautifully for the primary query (thank Stack Overflow!) but when I attempted to do the same exact join in the sub-query, I received the data type mismatch error.

Here is a picture, with a small arrow and text box to highlight the area which I (99% sure) believe is causing the problem. Again, the problem only arose when I attempted to join these two tables in the sub-query. If the join is removed, the query will run. (Although the sub-query will not return the correct results, thus making my primary query useless)

[image: My issue]

*All my Access DB's are set to accept Standard T-SQL syntax, so I will also tag this as T-SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the difference is probably that in the primary query you are excluding the cases where Crd Number is null, but in the subquery you are not. I don't have Access installed to be able to test, but I would bet it will work if you add to the subquery where clause.

```
sp.CRD_NUMBER is not null and dtp.CRD_NUMBER is not null
```

I suspect that the function CStr() is having a problem with null values, but then again, I can't test this to see if that would make a difference.

Comment: Thanks, I have already tried this and it doesn't seem to be the answer, but I am still playing around with it.

Comment: `SELECT  
sp.Trade_rep
FROM [SalesPage Reps] AS sp INNER JOIN [Ameriprise Reps DTP] AS dtp ON sp.CRD_NUMBER=dtp.[Crd Number]
WHERE 
sp.trade_firm = '0000###'
and sp.CRD_NUMBER Is Not Null
and sp.trade_office = dtp.[Dealerbrch];`

Comment: The above query works, but I didn't have to cast the data type in the join expression. This doesn't make sense to me, why would I have to cast the data type the first time I run a query with this same exact join, but not have to cast the exact same field in the exact same table when I run the query again? I have made absolutely zero updates to the linked source tables used in this database.

Comment: what data type is dtp.[brand rep id] and sp.trade_rep? what is the difference in the result set from just running the subquery with the on condition vs without the on?

Comment: both of those fields are textual fields already. I can set them = in the criteria and not have to cast the data type for either.

Comment: I got the query working, but I am still baffled as to why the sub-query requires me to NOT cast the data type of the joined column, while the primary query REQUIRES that I cast the data type of the joined column. The joined column in question being dtp.[crd number]. Oh well, I guess I should be happy it is working.

Comment: Also, while your post didn't technically answer my question, it helped me understand more about what was going on. I ended up dealing with Null values in the sub-query, so your advice helped. Answer accepted.